# generating a signature for AWS request logic - getting SignatureDoesNotMatch back

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to perform an upload to S3 using an HTML POST form along with an upload policy and I'm struggling with creating the signature to go along with it.

I keep getting back a 403 and SignatureDoesNotMatch response when I submit the upload form.

Using this as a guide, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html I've come up with the following:

```
policy_hash = {
  'expiration' => (Time.now.utc + 3600 * 3).iso8601
}

@policy = Base64.encode64(JSON.dump(policy_hash)).gsub("\n","")

kDate    = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', "AWS4" + @secret_access_key, Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
kRegion  = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kDate, AWS_REGION)
kService = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kRegion, "s3")
kSigning = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kService, "aws4_request")

@signature = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(
  OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kSigning, @policy)
)
```

And I am including the policy and signature in the from.  I know that `AWS_REGION` and `@secret_access_key` are correct because I am using them elsewhere.

Can anyone see anything wrong with the code above? or has any other guidance?

Answer (score 0):

```
@signature = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(
  OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kSigning, @policy)
 )
```

You're taking what should be your signature and instead of hex-encoding it, you're hashing it with SHA256 and hex-encoding the hash.

I'm not a ruby person, but here's a wild guess at what you actually need:

```
@signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', kSigning, @policy)
```

Comment: thanks for having a look, Michael. I decided to go down a different route and not code the signing logic myself in the end

Answer (score 0):

An update incase it helps anyone in the future, I ended up using the aws-sdk gem to handle all the signing and form building for me.

```
@s3_base_path = "#{SecureRandom.uuid}/"
creds = Aws::Credentials.new(access_key_id, secret_access_key, session_token)
@post = Aws::S3::PresignedPost.new(creds.credentials, AWS_REGION, S3_BRANDING_FILES_BUCKET, {
  key_starts_with: @s3_base_path,
  acl: 'private',
  success_action_status: '201',
  server_side_encryption: 'AES256',
  signature_expiration: Time.now.utc + 3600 * 3
})
```

And then in the view:

```
<!-- Direct Upload to S3 Form -->
<form action="<%= @post.url %>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <% @post.fields.each do |name, value| %>
    <input type="hidden" name="<%= name %>" value="<%= value %>"/>
  <% end %>

  <!-- Key is the file's name on S3 and will be filled in with JS -->
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="">
  <div class="hiddenfile" style="height:0; width:0; overflow:hidden;">
    <input type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" name="file" id="file-input">
  </div>
</form>
```